# How is this JavaScript function reducing the value in time?

Tags: javascript

I found this JavaScript function that works as a timer when provided values in seconds

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, hours, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        hours = parseInt(timer / 3600, 10)
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.text(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}


jQuery(function ($) {
    var fiveMinutes = {{step.duration.seconds}},
    display = $('#time');

    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
});
```

I am trying to under how the `setInterval` function is reducing the value of "time"? the --time is inside the If statement. I do not see any indication of reduction "time! values besides that.

Comment: `if (--timer < 0)` See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Decrement

Comment: the decrement will still be exectuted inside the if. you can also do simething like `if(const variable = get.some.value.which.is.truthly()) {}`

Comment: Let's start with the expression `timer++`. That's equivalent to `timer += 1`, which is equal to `timer = timer + 1`. `timer--` is the same thing, but decrementing (`timer -= 1`). When you put the operator in the prefix (`--timer` instead of `timer--`), the difference is that `timer--` returns the *current* value, and then decrements the variable, whereas `--timer` first decrements the variable, then returns that value. In your context, each time `setInterval` calls its callback, the expression in the `if` statement is evaluated. During evaluation, the value is decremented.